# Drupal 8 css and images relative to root

Tags: 8, caching, proxies, cdn

I have the challenge that I want my site to be cache-able by and external varnish cache provider.

Most of my page gets cached nicely, but elements like the ico file, images and css are written with the full url in code and hence doesn't use the cached version.

`www.domain.com` points to `internal.domain.com`

When I go to `www.domain.com` the urls for the images looks like this

```
http://internal.domain.com/sites/default/files/styles/hero_full/public/hero/image.jpg?itok=WiCUbqbj
```

What I wanted was that it just wrote a url relative to the root of the site.

```
/sites/default/files/styles/hero_full/public/hero/image.jpg?itok=WiCUbqbj
```

The issue is the same with files included from the THEME.libraries.yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core actually did exactly that change just a few days ago, it will be like that in 8.0.3.

That said, your set up looks problematic to me, that's not going to be the only thing that somehow relies on the domain name. Usually the same domain is used?

Comment: I am going to use Fastly as Caching service. They are going to get www pointed to them. Then I have a backend site that will be named internal.domain.com where Drupal lives. What solution would you else suggest?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the fix in 8.0.3 here is the link for the patch that fix my issue https://www.drupal.org/node/1494670 - and it is done by Wim Leers and I guess it is because of the caching issue to.

Comment: We use fastly too, I don't know our exact setup (we use platform.sh) but I know that drupal sees the same/public domain for incoming requests. Yes that issue was about caching but it was mostly about caching with http/https.